# How making an if else statement work in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to make an if statement that if the a meta data field is filled than post the youtube video, if it isn't than post the featured image on my single wordpress post page. I'm new to If else statements so I'm not sure if my syntax is right as I keep getting errors.

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post-video', true) ) : ?>
     <?php $youtube = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post-video', true);
     echo '<object width="720" height="405"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $youtube . '?version=3&hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $youtube . '?version=3&hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="720" height="405" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>';
     ?>
     <?php else 
        the_post_thumbnail('full'); 

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but as this is all php code you don't need to constantly define <?php ?>

Comment: You can check the documentation.A simple google search will provdide you so many results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<?php else:` in stead of `<?php else`

Hope will work!

Answer (score 0):

```
If (xxx) {
   // your code if true
} else {
   // your code if false
}
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post-video', true)){ 
    $youtube = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post-video', true)
    echo '<object width="720" height="405"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $youtube . '?version=3&hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $youtube . '?version=3&hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="720" height="405" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>';
} else { 
    the_post_thumbnail('full'); 
}
?>
```